# How to identify and eliminate overlaying polygons in Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, editing

I have a shapefile with polygons and now, not sure why, most of the polygons became duplicated and overlaid, i.e. when i click to selected one, i get two selected... How do i identify those polygons and remove them?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do it with Qgis itself, but you would be able to do it with GRASS.

See [accepted reply to that post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/remove-duplicate-polygons-using-open-source-tools). Or have a look on the [v.clean](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.clean.html) doc if you already are familiar to GRASS. See *tool=rmdac, rmdup* options.

Answer (score 4):

See MMQGIS Plugin with new tool (v2012.01.11) - Delete Duplicate Geometries
http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to identify and safely remove them you should try [kosmo](http://www.opengis.es/) or [openjump](http://www.openjump.org/) with the QA extension. Or you can try a more automated way with the grass modules from qgis http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb4iqRmcxHY

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 1.9.0 master (2.0) available plugin "Topology Checker". Links: [Topology Checker plugin on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huhkTZkoKC8), [Topology Checker plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/pull/425).
There is included 'must not overlap' and 'must not have duplicates' topology rules.

Comment: This plugin looks good for identifying problems - but how does it help the OP to __remove__ the problems?